# What is the meaning of starred angle for the third argument of \uput?

Tags: pstricks

Usually starred angle is used to cancel the rotation of the containing put macros, for example `\rput{90}(1,1){\rput{*0}(2,2){A}}` will keep the A upright.

When I apply a starred angle for the 3rd argument of `\uput`, I got the following output that I cannot figure out its meaning.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}


\newcommand{\object}[3]{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-1,0)(3,5)
    \pnode(1,2){A}
    \rput{\i}(A){%
        \psline(0,1)%
        \rput(0,1){\psline{->}(.5;#2)}%
        \pscircle(0,1){.5}%
        \uput{.5}[#2]{#3}(0,1){\pspolygon[linecolor=red,unit=.25](-1,-1)(-1,0)(0,1)(1,0)(1,-1)}%
        \uput{.5}[#2]{*#3}(0,1){\pspolygon[linecolor=green,unit=.25](-1,-1)(-1,0)(0,1)(1,0)(1,-1)}%
    }
    \qdisk(A){2pt}  
    \rput*(1,4.5){\textbackslash uput\{.\}[#2]\{*#3\}(.)\{\}}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+30}{13}{\object{\i}{0}{90}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: The second argument of `\uput` cannot receive starred angle. I also want to know the reason why.

Comment: Try your example with `ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None <file>` or `-dAutoRotatePages#/None`  for Windows

Comment: The second argument is the rotation of the label around its coordinates and not the rotation around the origin. The label itself doesn't rotate.

Comment: your example shows the expected behaviour. The circle moves 30 degrees counter clockwise which is the reason why the green polygon moves 30 degrees clockwise. Hence it ignores the rotation in fact of the star.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](-4,-4)(4,4)
\uput{.3}[0]{45}(0,1){$30^\circ$}
\rput{-45}(2,2){\uput{.3}[0]{45}(0,1){$30^\circ$}}
\rput{-45}(2,-2){\uput{.3}[0]{*45}(0,1){(*)$30^\circ$}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Understood??

Comment: (*) ignores a preceeding rotation, the reason why in the last example the first `-45` of `\rput` is not taken into account for `\uput`. It uses only its own `45°`